# Find formula to describe recursion in method

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, equation

I am struggling with writing the formula that describes the recursive nature of the `foo` method.

[image: Recursive function]

The problem is that as far as I can tell, since every time `n` is divided with `2`,

the binary tree formula should apply here.

This says that when in each call we divide the data we get a formula like this:

[image: Recursion formula]

And then if we analyze for `2` so [image]:

We get:

[image]

Which means that `C(N) = log(N + 1), namely O(logN)`

That all makes sense and seems to be the right choice for the `foo` method but it cant be because for

`n = 8` I would get `3 + 1` iterations that are not `n + 1 = 8 + 1 = 9` iterations

Comment: ```C(N) = log(N + 1)``` is correct, why are you using ```n``` and ```N``` separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is your code:

```
void foo(int n) {
    if (n == 1) System.out.println("Last line I print");
    if (n > 1) {
        System.out.println("I am printing one more line");
        foo(n/2);
    }
}
```

We can write a recurrence relation down for its runtime T as a function of the value of the parameter passed into it, n:

```
T(1) = a, a constant
T(n) = b + T(n/2), b constant, n > 1
```

We can write out some values of T(n) for various values of n to see if a pattern emerges:

```
n    T(n)
---------
1    a
2    a + b
4    a + 2b
8    a + 3b
...
2^k  a + kb
```

So for n = 2^k, T(n) = a + kb. We can solve for k in terms of n as follows:

```
n = 2^k <=> k = log(n)
```

Then we recover the expression T(n) = a + blog(n). We can verify this expression works easily:

```
a + blog(1) = a, as required

a + blog(n) = b + (a + blog(n/2))
            = b + (a + b(log(n) - 1)
            = b + a + blog(n) - b
            = a + blog(n), as required
```

You can also use mathematical induction to do the same thing.